Counting Sublists by Their First Element
Given the following list, count the number of sublists with the same first element.
list = {{1, 4}, {1, 8}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 12}, {3, 4}, {3, 8}, {3, 
   12}, {3, 16}, {4, 4}, {4, 8}, {4, 12}, {4, 16}, {4, 20}, {4, 24}}

My method is:
list = {{1, 4}, {1, 8}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 12}, {3, 4}, {3, 8}, {3, 
    12}, {3, 16}, {4, 4}, {4, 8}, {4, 12}, {4, 16}, {4, 20}, {4, 
    24}};
Length /@ GroupBy[list, First]

Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Tally[First /@ list]

(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}} *)


Using Tally:
Association[#1[[1]] -> #2 & @@@ Tally[list, #2[[1]] === #1[[1]] &]]


<|1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 6|>

Or using CountsBy:
CountsBy[list, First]


<|1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 6|>

